# My recently deleted comments should remain in the Comments view

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

Can my recently deleted comments remain viewable for some time by me in the Comments view of the Activity tab, especially when they weren't deleted by me?

I suggested a simple edit in a Math.SE answer, as a comment. (I did also upvote the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/638666/820), but had no reason to favourite the question.)

The answerer did make the edit, and then someone deleted my comment. So I had only my memory of the question title in (my upvote list, which I didn't use or) Google Chrome's history of pages visited (which *is* where I went to find it).

(I assume someone decided my comment wasn't needed now that the edit had been made. This is a fair enough decision, but can they wait a day or two to allow me to decide to delete it myself :-) )